# Linux bash for do loop dynamic parameter substitution

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

I want to use a bash command that I assume would be something along lines of

```
for f in *.xml; do mv $f StaticTextPrefix + ./GetXmlSpecificNodeValue $f + StaticTextSuffix; done
```

So the program GetXmlSpecificNodeValue returns a unique value from the XML found which will be guaranteed to be unique for each xml file.

Is this possible what does the structure of the command look like?

Comment: Just `mv "$f" "StaticTextPrefix/$(GetXmlSpecificNodeValue "$f")StaticTextSuffix"`?

Answer (score 0):

thankyou @KamilCuk
had to prefix the GetXmlSpecificNodeValue with ./ but otherwise it works

```
for f in *.xml; do mv $f "StaticTextPrefix/$(./GetXmlSpecificNodeValue "$f")StaticTextSuffix"; done
```